# What event listener should I use to tie my select menu to my calendar and how?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, calendar

I'm writing a calendar using Javascript, and I can't figure out how to tie my select menu to my calendar. There are two select menus, one for choosing months, the other for years. By default, the calendar shows the current month and year, but when the user selects something from the drop down menu it should change the calendar to the selected date.

After searching the web and trying all the methods that I found, nothing has yet worked for me.

```
function listenMonths() {
    let select = document.getElementById('months');
/*
    select.onchange = changeEventHandler('change');

    function changeEventHandler(event) {
        currentMonth = this; // event.target.value;
    }
*/
    select.addEventListener('change', function() {
        currentMonth = this;
    })
}
```

Above is a piece of my code, the listener for Months' select menu. The commented out piece is the second method from MDN.

I'm stuck and I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're calling `listenMonths()` at the appropriate time, what you've posted should work, but it depends on what you want `currentMonth` to be set to; in this context, `this` may not be what you're looking for. `this.value` will return the value you've assigned to the options in your `select` menu.

[This JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TobyRush/zk34fLvL/) works for me. Feel free to post more of your code if it doesn't address your problem.